# Is there a word "immensly rigorous but enriching"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I'm not looking for denotations here, and it could be multiple words. I'm just looking for something more meaningful. I need a word(s) that truly show how immense this is.

Context: 
...the relationship becomes less like intersecting hikes and more like a single, "immense and enriching journey".

Comment: What about *profound*?

Comment: You should provide more context. I am at lost even after reading it a few times.

Comment: *engrossing* is a word that comes to mind that suggests something enriching that catches one's full attention.  ..not necessarily 'rigorous'

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple words that can mean an immense, enriching journey:

[**Odyssey:**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/odyssey/) a long and eventful or adventurous journey or experience
 
[**Trek:**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trek/) a long arduous journey, especially one made on foot
 
[**Quest:**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quest/) a long or arduous search for something

I personally think "**Odyssey**" works pretty well for your case given the context.

*(All definitions via Oxford Dictionary)*

Answer (score 1):

What about "**edifying**"- *"instructive or informative in a way that improves the mind or character "*

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edifying

Answer (score 0):

Profound is lovely, Nagarajan.

But if you're talking about the meaningful achievement of completing multi-day hikes over long distances (I've done a fair few), you could say something like:

'The relationship becomes less like a series of intersecting hikes and more like one single journey of the soul.'

Too cheesy?
;)